# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I got a problem with `else` function.

Here is my code

```
IF (Not Exists(SELECT * FROM Log_DB.dbo._LogJobSYS WHERE KillerJobID=@JKillerID AND DeadJobID=@CharID)) 
    BEGIN
        INSERT Log_DB.dbo._LogJobSYS(KillerJobID,DeadJobID,DeathTime)
        VALUES (@JKillerID, @CharID, GETDATE())
        BEGIN
            BEGIN
                IF (@JKillerJobType = 1) /*TRADER*/ 
                BEGIN
                IF (Not Exists(SELECT * FROM SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobTradersys Where CharID=@JKillerID))
                BEGIN
                INSERT SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobTradersys(CharID,TraderPoints,Kills,Deaths,LastKill,Date)
                VALUES (@JKillerID, 1, 1, 0, @JDeadNick, GETDATE())
                END
                ELSE Begin
                UPDATE SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobTradersys SET TraderPoints = TraderPoints +1, Kills = Kills +1, LastKill = @JDeadNick, Date = GETDATE() WHERE CharID = @JKillerID
                END
                END
            END
            ELSE 
                IF (@JKillerJobType = 2) /*THIEF*/ 
                BEGIN
                IF (Not Exists(SELECT * FROM SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobThiefsys Where CharID=@JKillerID))
                BEGIN
                INSERT SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobThiefsys(CharID,ThiefPoints,Kills,Deaths,LastKill,Date)
                VALUES (@JKillerID, 1, 1, 0, @JDeadNick, GETDATE())
                END
                ELSE Begin
                UPDATE SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobThiefsys SET ThiefPoints = ThiefPoints +1, Kills = Kills +1, LastKill = @JDeadNick, Date = GETDATE() WHERE CharID = @JKillerID
                END

            END
            ELSE 
                IF (@JKillerJobType = 3) /*HUNTER*/ 
                BEGIN
                IF (Not Exists(SELECT * FROM SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobHuntersys Where CharID=@JKillerID))
                BEGIN
                INSERT SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobHuntersys(CharID,HunterPoints,Kills,Deaths,LastKill,Date)
                VALUES (@JKillerID, 1, 1, 0, @JDeadNick, GETDATE())
                END
                ELSE Begin
                UPDATE SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobHuntersys SET HunterPoints = HunterPoints +1, Kills = Kills +1, LastKill = @JDeadNick, Date = GETDATE() WHERE CharID = @JKillerID
                END

            END 
            BEGIN
                IF (@JDeadJobType = 1) /*TRADER*/ 
                BEGIN
                IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobTradersys WHERE CharID=@CharID))
                BEGIN
                INSERT SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobTradersys(CharID,TraderPoints,Kills,Deaths,LastKill,Date)
                VALUES (@CharID, 0, 0, 1, 'NONE', GETDATE())
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                UPDATE SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobTradersys SET TraderPoints = TraderPoints -0.5, Deaths = Deaths +1, Date = GETDATE() WHERE CharID = @CharID
                END
                END
            END 
            ELSE  
                IF (@JDeadJobType = 2) /*THIEF*/ 
                BEGIN
                IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobThiefsys WHERE CharID=@CharID))
                BEGIN
                INSERT SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobThiefsys(CharID,ThiefPoints,Kills,Deaths,LastKill,Date)
                VALUES (@CharID, 0, 0, 1, 'NONE', GETDATE())
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                UPDATE SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobThiefsys SET ThiefPoints = ThiefPoints -0.5, Deaths = Deaths +1, Date = GETDATE() WHERE CharID = @CharID
                END

            END
            ELSE 
                IF (@JDeadJobType = 3) /*HUNTER*/ 
                BEGIN
                IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobHuntersys WHERE CharID=@CharID))
                BEGIN
                INSERT SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobHuntersys(CharID,HunterPoints,Kills,Deaths,LastKill,Date)
                VALUES (@CharID, 0, 0, 1, 'NONE', GETDATE())
                END
                ELSE BEGIN
                UPDATE SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobHuntersys SET HunterPoints = HunterPoints -0.5, Deaths = Deaths +1, Date = GETDATE() WHERE CharID = @CharID
                END

            END
        END
    END
```

I get these errors:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure _AddLogChar, Line 155
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure _AddLogChar, Line 194
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.

Side note : this is for the first `Else` command but the second one doesn't give error (the ones which are before IF (@JKillerJobType = 2) AND IF (@JDeadJobType = 2) !
thanks !

Comment: it appears you have two "ELSE"s before IF (@JDeadJobType = 2) and IF (@JDeadJobType = 3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have commented out some of the suspicious ENDs have a look now,  With such a complex query Indentation really make things much easier.

```
IF (Not Exists(SELECT * FROM Log_DB.dbo._LogJobSYS WHERE KillerJobID=@JKillerID AND DeadJobID=@CharID)) 
    BEGIN
        INSERT Log_DB.dbo._LogJobSYS(KillerJobID,DeadJobID,DeathTime)
        VALUES (@JKillerID, @CharID, GETDATE())
        BEGIN

                IF (@JKillerJobType = 1) /*TRADER*/ 
                    BEGIN
                        IF (Not Exists(SELECT * FROM SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobTradersys Where CharID=@JKillerID))
                          BEGIN
                             INSERT SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobTradersys(CharID,TraderPoints,Kills,Deaths,LastKill,Date)
                             VALUES (@JKillerID, 1, 1, 0, @JDeadNick, GETDATE())
                           END
                        ELSE 
                          Begin
                            UPDATE SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobTradersys SET TraderPoints = TraderPoints +1, Kills = Kills +1, LastKill = @JDeadNick, Date = GETDATE() WHERE CharID = @JKillerID
                          END
                    END
                    --END  --<-- This End

                    ELSE IF (@JKillerJobType = 2) /*THIEF*/ 
                      BEGIN
                             IF (Not Exists(SELECT * FROM SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobThiefsys Where CharID=@JKillerID))
                                BEGIN
                                    INSERT SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobThiefsys(CharID,ThiefPoints,Kills,Deaths,LastKill,Date)
                                    VALUES (@JKillerID, 1, 1, 0, @JDeadNick, GETDATE())
                                END
                        ELSE 
                            Begin
                                UPDATE SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobThiefsys SET ThiefPoints = ThiefPoints +1, Kills = Kills +1, LastKill = @JDeadNick, Date = GETDATE() WHERE CharID = @JKillerID
                            END

                      END

                    ELSE IF (@JKillerJobType = 3) /*HUNTER*/ 
                      BEGIN
                            IF (Not Exists(SELECT * FROM SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobHuntersys Where CharID=@JKillerID))
                                BEGIN
                                    INSERT SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobHuntersys(CharID,HunterPoints,Kills,Deaths,LastKill,Date)
                                    VALUES (@JKillerID, 1, 1, 0, @JDeadNick, GETDATE())
                                END
                            ELSE 
                                Begin
                                    UPDATE SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobHuntersys SET HunterPoints = HunterPoints +1, Kills = Kills +1, LastKill = @JDeadNick, Date = GETDATE() WHERE CharID = @JKillerID
                            END

                      END 
                    BEGIN IF (@JDeadJobType = 1) /*TRADER*/ 
                        BEGIN
                                IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobTradersys WHERE CharID=@CharID))
                                    BEGIN
                                        INSERT SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobTradersys(CharID,TraderPoints,Kills,Deaths,LastKill,Date)
                                        VALUES (@CharID, 0, 0, 1, 'NONE', GETDATE())
                                    END
                                ELSE 
                                    BEGIN
                                        UPDATE SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobTradersys SET TraderPoints = TraderPoints -0.5, Deaths = Deaths +1, Date = GETDATE() WHERE CharID = @CharID
                                    END
                        END
                    --END   --<--  this End  
                    ELSE  IF (@JDeadJobType = 2) /*THIEF*/ 
                        BEGIN
                                IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobThiefsys WHERE CharID=@CharID))
                                    BEGIN
                                        INSERT SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobThiefsys(CharID,ThiefPoints,Kills,Deaths,LastKill,Date)
                                        VALUES (@CharID, 0, 0, 1, 'NONE', GETDATE())
                                    END
                                ELSE 
                                    BEGIN
                                        UPDATE SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobThiefsys SET ThiefPoints = ThiefPoints -0.5, Deaths = Deaths +1, Date = GETDATE() WHERE CharID = @CharID
                                END

                        END
                    ELSE IF (@JDeadJobType = 3) /*HUNTER*/ 
                        BEGIN
                                IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobHuntersys WHERE CharID=@CharID))
                                    BEGIN
                                        INSERT SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobHuntersys(CharID,HunterPoints,Kills,Deaths,LastKill,Date)
                                        VALUES (@CharID, 0, 0, 1, 'NONE', GETDATE())
                                    END
                                ELSE 
                                    BEGIN
                                        UPDATE SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobHuntersys SET HunterPoints = HunterPoints -0.5, Deaths = Deaths +1, Date = GETDATE() WHERE CharID = @CharID
                             END

                      END
               END  
          END
   END
```

Comment: thanks alot just copied it and it's working
also i know where was the errors as u said :D

Comment: Wow really didnt expect it to :) well glad it worked all I did was properly indented it which makes easier to read complex code.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may be missing a few 'END's.  Unless you mean to nest deeper. For the TRADER type, you close all the way out, but for THIEF on down you do not.

```
BEGIN
        BEGIN
            IF (@JKillerJobType = 1) /*TRADER*/ 
            BEGIN
                IF (Not Exists(SELECT * FROM SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobTradersys Where CharID=@JKillerID))
                BEGIN
                    INSERT SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobTradersys(CharID,TraderPoints,Kills,Deaths,LastKill,Date)
                    VALUES (@JKillerID, 1, 1, 0, @JDeadNick, GETDATE())
                END
                ELSE 
                Begin
                    UPDATE SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobTradersys SET TraderPoints = TraderPoints +1, Kills = Kills +1, LastKill = @JDeadNick, Date = GETDATE() WHERE CharID = @JKillerID
                END
            END
        END
        ELSE 
            IF (@JKillerJobType = 2) /*THIEF*/ 
            BEGIN
                IF (Not Exists(SELECT * FROM SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobThiefsys Where CharID=@JKillerID))
                BEGIN
                    INSERT SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobThiefsys(CharID,ThiefPoints,Kills,Deaths,LastKill,Date)
                    VALUES (@JKillerID, 1, 1, 0, @JDeadNick, GETDATE())
                END
                ELSE 
                Begin
                    UPDATE SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobThiefsys SET ThiefPoints = ThiefPoints +1, Kills = Kills +1, LastKill = @JDeadNick, Date = GETDATE() WHERE CharID = @JKillerID
                END
            END
            ELSE 
                IF (@JKillerJobType = 3) /*HUNTER*/ 
                BEGIN
                    IF (Not Exists(SELECT * FROM SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobHuntersys Where CharID=@JKillerID))
                    BEGIN
                    INSERT SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobHuntersys(CharID,HunterPoints,Kills,Deaths,LastKill,Date)
                    VALUES (@JKillerID, 1, 1, 0, @JDeadNick, GETDATE())
                END
                ELSE 
                Begin
                    UPDATE SRO_VT_SHARD_INIT.dbo._CharJobHuntersys SET HunterPoints = HunterPoints +1, Kills = Kills +1, LastKill = @JDeadNick, Date = GETDATE() WHERE CharID = @JKillerID
                END
```

Comment: when i tried to remove the ends with close the way and but it at the last of SP it executed successfully but only the last command which of IF (@JDeadJobType = 1) /*TRADER*/ (look for it in main question) is working , others not

Comment: thanks it works just seems i miss smth which is responsible to declare of @JKillerJobType so it's not working :s

Answer (score 0):

Put square brackets around _AddLogChar.  [_AddLogChar]

Comment: _AddLogChar is the name of the stored procedures !

Comment: Sorry. Not entirely clear.  My next guess was @mgoodric's.  With all of that, mostly likely missing or too many END's or BEGINS.  Is there any reason why you cannot simply it using a few case statements.  There is a lot of duplication around CharJobThiefsys  and CharJobHuntSys.  Case when CharJobThier is null and CharJobHunt is not null, etc.